# VSFTPD stops responding at password request

Tags: 14.04, vsftpd

FTP stops responding at password request.  After requesting password FTP client immediately gives a `connection failed` message.  Service has been working for several years but we only use it periodically on the LAN.
Some update may have broken it, but I didn't installed nothing new lately so I don't think that it is.

I'm running `vsftpd` (version 3.0.2) on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

At the moment it allow only local users. Log shows:

```
Fri Apr 22 09:17:15 2016 [pid 9807] CONNECT: Client "192.168.1.8"  
Fri Apr 22 09:17:15 2016 [pid 9807] FTP response: Client "192.168.1.8", "220 Welcome to APP CNC FTP service."  
Fri Apr 22 09:17:15 2016 [pid 9807] FTP command: Client "192.168.1.8", "USER mazak"  
Fri Apr 22 09:17:15 2016 [pid 9807] [mazak] FTP response: Client "192.168.1.8", "331 Please specify the password."  
Fri Apr 22 09:17:15 2016 [pid 9807] [mazak] FTP command: Client "192.168.1.8", "PASS <password>"
```

Netstat after freezing

```
sudo netstat --proto=inet,inet6 -avpnl | grep ":21"  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9718/vsftpd  
tcp        1      0 192.168.1.192:21        192.168.1.8:59370       CLOSE_WAIT  9725/vsftpd
```

Have to restart the service to get it to respond again.

Comment: More information: "ftp local host" fails with message _The "syslog" option is deprecated_  after asking for the password

Answer (score 0):

The ***"The "syslog" option is deprecated"*** issue is related to Samba server not having the correct config.  I was getting the same error in Ubuntu terminal when using SUDO, in Filezilla when using FTP, and in Fog server.  The solution that removed this error:

https://bugs.freenas.org/issues/14231

I edited my Samba config file following these tips.  I commented out usage of **syslog** and **syslog only** in the Samba config:

> Use "logging" parameter to configure Samba logging instead of
>   deprecated "syslog" and "syslog only"